# Export non-empty rows into individual CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a report that has empty rows with lines of data spread throughout.

I use this to export the entire page as one CSV:

```vb
Sub NoNullSaveCSVrows()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Application.Workbooks.Add xlWBATWorksheet
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
        .Range("A1:J400").Copy
        WS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    WS.Range("A1").Value = "FilterCol"
    WS.Columns.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
    WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    WS.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    WB.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dataupload.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    WB.Close False
End Sub
```

Is there a modification that could be made to export individual lines with data as its own CSV, preferably named like *firstcell*.csv or something.